# Anonymous class inheritance

Tags: inheritance, python

I am building a python automation API around a device configuration that looks like this...

```
root@EX4200-24T# show interfaces ge-0/0/6 
mtu 9216;
unit 0 {
    family ethernet-switching {
        port-mode trunk;
        vlan {
            members [ v100 v101 v102 ];
        }
    }
}

root@EX4200-24T#
```

I am defining python classes for certain actions (like SET), as well as classes for the keywords for the action...  The idea is that SET would iterate through the keyword classes and attach the class objects to the interfaces.

The problem is that the configuration of this device is quite hierarchical... for instance if there are many `ethernet-switching` instances, I don't want API users to have to use:

```
# Note that each keyword corresponds to a python class that is appended
# to an InterfaceList object behind the scenes...
SET(Interface='ge-0/0/6.0', Family='ethernet-switching', PortMode='trunk', 
    Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
SET(Interface='ge-0/0/7.0', Family='ethernet-switching', PortMode='trunk', 
    Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
SET(Interface='ge-0/0/8.0', Family='ethernet-switching', PortMode='trunk', 
    Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
```

Instead I would like to be able to use:

```
Family('ethernet-switching')
SET(Interface='ge-0/0/6.0', PortMode='trunk', Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
SET(Interface='ge-0/0/7.0', PortMode='trunk', Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
SET(Interface='ge-0/0/8.0', PortMode='trunk', Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
Family(None)
# API usage continues...
```

However, I can't figure out a way to code this in python without resorting to something like this...

```
f = Family('ethernet-switching')
f.SET(Interface='ge-0/0/6.0', PortMode='trunk', 
    Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
f.SET(Interface='ge-0/0/7.0', PortMode='trunk', 
    Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
f.SET(Interface='ge-0/0/8.0', PortMode='trunk', 
    Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
```

Which is not so bad until I need `SET()` to inherit from multiple classes... such as...

*PREFERRED API*

```
# Note: there could be many combinations of classes to inherit from
Family('ethernet-switching')
PortMode('trunk')
SET(Interface='ge-0/0/6.0', Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
SET(Interface='ge-0/0/7.0', Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
PortMode('access')
SET(Interface='ge-0/0/8.0', Vlan=['v100'])
SET(Interface='ge-0/0/9.0', Vlan=['v100'])
Family(None)
PortMode(None)
```

Is there a pythonic way to achieve the last API example I have?  If not, can you share some ideas for how to code the hierarchy of classes?

Comment: PEP8 advises to not put spaces around the `=` for keyword parameters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does something like this help you?

```
from functools import partial
S=partial(SET, Family='ethernet-switching', PortMode='trunk')
S(Interface='ge-0/0/6.0', Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
S(Interface='ge-0/0/7.0', Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
S(Interface='ge-0/0/8.0', Vlan=['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])
```

Comment: this is so elegant, I was laughing out loud at how much I could have simplified piles of past code (and saved much headache).  I wish I could give +5 for it.

Comment: +1: This is neat! Great nuggets like these are why I'm hooked to SO!

Answer (score 2):

gnibbler's use of `functools.partial` is indeed an elegant approach, but if you want to look at a true implicit context based approach, I suggested exploring the implementation details underlying `decimal.getcontext()`, `decimal.setcontext()` and `decimal.localcontext()`.

Documentation is at: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/decimal
Source code is at: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/decimal.py#l435

Comment: That's a great reference, thank you.  Actually you answered my exact question, but I will probably use gnibber's solution more often than this.  This would have been my accepted answer if gnibber had not provided such a creative solution first.

Comment: Heh, I actually upvoted gnibbler's answer as well. The thread-local context approach is serious overkill in most cases - partial application is significantly simpler if it is sufficient for the task.

Answer (score 1):

Well this resembles `jQuery` selection & filtering API, where they make use of function chaining:

```
some_set_of_data
    .filter(first_criteria)
        .filter(second_criteria)
```

They also introduced `end()` method that allows you to do things like that:

```
some_set_of_data
    .filter(first_criteria)
        .filter(second_criteria)
            .do_something()
        .end()
        .do_something_else()
```

Note that in this example `do_something()` is called on data filtered by both `first_criteria` and `second_criteria`, wheras `do_something_else()` is called on the data only filtered by the `first_criteria`.

It should be fairly easy to copy this kind of approach in Python that has a lot in common with JavaScript.

Comment: you are suggesting something like this:  `Family('ethernet-switching').PortMode('trunk').SET(Interface = 'ge-0/0/6.0', Vlan = ['v100', 'v101', 'v102']).SET(Interface = 'ge-0/0/7.0', Vlan = ['v100', 'v101', 'v102'])`?  I suppose that is possible, but that would make for enormous lines for some of the tasks API users need to accomplish... I'm really trying to avoid driving them to long chains of functions in one line...

Comment: Well maybe you could nest python context managers then: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typecontextmanager.html, if you don't want to chain functions.